# Check that model has only one factor covariate

Tags: r, formula, glm, lm, model.matrix

I am writing an R package, where the main function takes a **model, which may only have a single factor covariate** (offsets are allowed). To make sure the user complies with this rule I need to check this.

As an example, let's look at the following four models:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 10 

## data
data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(n), 
  trt = rep(c(0, 1), each = n/2),
  x = 1:n)
datan <- data
datan$trt <- as.factor(datan$trt)

## models
mod1 <- lm(y ~ factor(trt), data = data)
mod2 <- lm(y ~ offset(x) + as.factor(trt), data = data)
mod3 <- lm(y ~ trt, data = datan)
mod4 <- glm(y ~ trt + offset(x), data = data)
mod5 <- lm(y ~ x + as.factor(trt), data = data)
```

Models **1, 2 and 3 are ok**, models **4 and 5 are not ok** (model 4 has a non-factor variable `trt`, model 5 has a second covariate `x`).

How do I check this using R? Optimally I'd get a `TRUE` for a model that's ok, and a `FALSE` for a problematic model.

This should work not only with `lm()` and `glm()`, but also with `survreg()` and `coxph()` (from package survival). Something that might be useful is looking at the formula `eval(getCall(mod1)$formula)` and the data (`data`/ `datan`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the previous reply by @LAP you can use the `terms()` from these models. However, I would recommend to look at the `attr(..., "factors")` and `attr(..., "dataClasses")` instead of going to the `$model` which requires that the entire `model.frame()` is stored in the model. This may or may not be the case. Specifically, when re-fitting multiple models you might want to be able to not store the model frame each time.

So one idea would be to proceed in the following steps:

- Check whether `attr(..., "factors")` has not exactly one column, the you can return `FALSE`.
- If there is exactly one factor, you can check the corresponding `attr(..., "dataClasses")` if it is `"factor"`/`"ordered"` and then return `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`.

R code:

```
one_factor <- function(object) {
  f <- attr(terms(object), "factors")
  if(length(f) == 0L || NCOL(f) != 1L) return(FALSE)
  d <- attr(terms(object), "dataClasses")
  if(d[colnames(f)] %in% c("ordered", "factor")) {
    return(TRUE)
  } else {
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
```

This appears to work well for single-part `formula`-based objects.

Dummy data with numeric/factor/ordered `trt`:

```
d1 <- d2 <- d3 <- data.frame(y = log(1:9), x = 1:9, trt = rep(1:3, each = 3)) 
d2$trt <- factor(d2$trt)
d3$trt <- ordered(d3$trt)
```

Various formula specifications:

```
f <- list(
  y ~ 1,
  y ~ x,
  y ~ trt,
  y ~ trt + x,
  y ~ trt + offset(x),
  y ~ trt + x + offset(x),
  y ~ trt + offset(as.numeric(trt)),
  y ~ factor(trt),
  y ~ factor(trt) + offset(x),
  y ~ factor(x > as.numeric(trt)),
  y ~ interaction(x, trt),
  y ~ 0 + trt
)
```

Expected results for `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`, respectively:

```
ok1 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
ok2 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
ok3 <- ok2
```

Checks for `lm` without storing the model frame:

```
lm1 <- lapply(f, lm, data = d1, model = FALSE)
identical(sapply(lm1, one_factor), ok1)
## [1] TRUE
lm2 <- lapply(f, lm, data = d2, model = FALSE)
identical(sapply(lm2, one_factor), ok2)
## [1] TRUE
lm3 <- lapply(f, lm, data = d3, model = FALSE)
identical(sapply(lm3, one_factor), ok3)
## [1] TRUE
```

Checks for `survreg` (Gaussian) and `coxph`. (The latter throws a lot of warnings about non-convergence which is not surprising given the dummy data structure. The checks still work as intended.)

```
library("survival")
d1$y <- d2$y <- d3$y <- Surv(d1$y + 0.5)

sr1 <- lapply(f, survreg, data = d1)
identical(sapply(sr1, one_factor), ok1)
## [1] TRUE
sr2 <- lapply(f, survreg, data = d2)
identical(sapply(sr2, one_factor), ok2)
## [1] TRUE
sr3 <- lapply(f, survreg, data = d3)
identical(sapply(sr3, one_factor), ok3)
## [1] TRUE

cph1 <- lapply(f, coxph, data = d1)
identical(sapply(cph1, one_factor), ok1)
## [1] TRUE
cph2 <- lapply(f, coxph, data = d2)
identical(sapply(cph2, one_factor), ok2)
## [1] TRUE
cph3 <- lapply(f, coxph, data = d3)
identical(sapply(cph3, one_factor), ok3)
## [1] TRUE
```

*Note:* If you have multi-part `Formula`-based objects this function might fail and the underlying tests would need to be adapted. Examples for the latter could include count regression models (`zeroinfl`, `hurdle`), multinomial logit (`mlogit`), instrumental variables (`ivreg`), heteroscedastic models (`vglm`, `betareg`, `crch`) etc. These might have formulas like `y ~ trt | 1` or `y ~ trt | trt` or `y ~ trt | x` which may or may not still be feasible in your framework.

Answer (score 0):

This will need some more testing, but it works for your examples:

```
FOO <- function(x){
  vars <- labels(terms(x))
  test <- sapply(x$model[vars], class)
  all(test == "factor", length(test) == 1)
}
```

We first extract the covariates of the model using `labels(terms())`, which has the added benefit to ignore offsets, then get a vector of the classes and test whether the two conditions (1. variable is a factor, 2. it is only one variable) are true.

```
> sapply(list(mod1, mod2, mod3, mod4, mod5), FOO)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```